# System Rescue CD on multiboot usb not working

Tags: usb, multi-boot, livecd, usb-3

I have a multiboot usb with System Rescue CD and GRUB2 on it.  When I try to boot it, it tries to find systemrescuecd/sysrcd.dat, attempts to mount /dev/sr0 and all the partitions on /dev/sda before declaring `cannot find systemrescuecd/sysrcd.dat on devices` and dumping me onto a primitive shell. The relevant entries in grub.cfg:

```
menuentry "SystemRescueCd 32bit" {
linux /systemrescuecd/isolinux/rescuecd rootfs=/systemrescuecd subdir=systemrescuecd dostartx setkmap=us
initrd /systemrescuecd/isolinux/initram.igz
}
menuentry "SystemRescueCd 64bit" {
linux /systemrescuecd/isolinux/rescue64 rootfs=/systemrescuecd subdir=systemrescuecd dostartx setkmap=us
initrd /systemrescuecd/isolinux/initram.igz
}
```

I *think* the problem is that System Rescue CD cannot see /dev/sdb, which is my usb, but I don't know where to begin to fix it.  If it helps, I set up my USB with a utility called MultiSystem, which is like MultiISO for Linux.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A bit late, but the problem had to do with USB 3.0 slot driver support.  System Rescue CD doesn't have USB 3.0 driver or they aren't being loaded (correctly).